# Using filter on an item in a list?

Tags: list, haskell, filter

I am trying to filter by an item in a list and print them line by line. Here's my code:

```
data Car = Car String [String] Int [String]

testDatabase :: [Car]
testDatabase = [Car"Casino Royale" ["Daniel Craig"] 2006 ["Garry", "Dave", "Zoe", "Kevin", "Emma"],Car"Blade Runner" ["Harrison Ford", "Rutger Hauer"] 1982 ["Dave", "Zoe", "Amy", "Bill", "Ian", "Kevin", "Emma", "Sam", "Megan"]]



formatCarRow (Car a b c d) =  show a ++ " | " ++ concat [i ++ ", " | i <- init b] ++ last b ++ " | " ++ show c ++ " | " ++ concat [j ++ ", " | j <- init d] ++ last d



displayFilmsByYear :: String -> IO [()]
displayFilmsByYear chosenYear = mapM (putStrLn.formatFilmRow) [putStrLn(filter ((== chosenYear).y)) |  (w x y z) <- testDatabase] -- This is the code not working i think
```

Why isnt this working?

Comment: Did you mean `data Film = Car …`? Otherwise there’s a type mismatch in `testDatabase`. Similar for `formatFilmRow` / `formatCarRow`.

Comment: ive edited this now, sorry this wasnt the problem the original problem is still there :/

Comment: Just out of curiosity: do you use a random generator to decide on placement of the word putStrLn in your program text? Just kidding .... :)

Comment: please consider to divide your program into many smaller functions. Then you'll be able to think clearer. Even though the specific problem here is something else, once you organize up your code, the error will hopefully reveal itself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you wish to filter a list, I recommend using the `filter` function :)

```
data Car = Car String [String] Int [String]

year :: Car -> Int
year (Car _ _ y _) = y

filterByYear :: Int -> [Car] -> [Car]
filterByYear chosenYear cars = filter (\car -> year car == chosenYear) cars

showCar :: Car -> String
showCar car = undefined -- you can implement this how you like

displayCarsByYear :: Int -> IO ()
displayCarsByYear chosenYear = mapM_ (putStrLn . showCar) filteredCars
    where filteredCars = filterByYear chosenYear testDatabase
```

It seems wise to explain a few things here:

**Anonymous Functions**: `(\car -> year car == chosenYear)` is an anonymous function. It takes one argument and calls it `car`. Then it determines whether that car's year is equal to the `chosenYear`. I didn't explicitly write this function's type signature, but it's `Car -> Bool`.

**Filtering**: I gave that function to `filter`, so that it would look through the list of `Car`s. When `filter` finds cars for which that function returns `True`, it puts them in the result list. A `False` result means that a car doesn't make it through the filter.

**Function composition**: `(putStrLn . showCar)` This is a function that first performs `showCar`, and then uses `putStrLn` on the result of `showCar`.

**Where**: You'll notice the `where` statement at the end of my code. It should be fairly self-explanatory, you can use either `let` or `where` statements to define "local variables". As a matter of taste, I prefer where over let.

**List comprenensions vs filter**: List comprehensions can filter a list just like the filter function. For a function `f :: a -> Bool`, and a list `xs :: [a]`

`filter f xs` is the same as `[x | x <- xs, f x]`. As a matter of taste, I prefer spelling out `filter` in such cases, since it makes it very clear that I'm filtering the list.

See also [LYAH # Maps and filters](http://learnyouahaskell.com/higher-order-functions#maps-and-filters)

--

**Further recommendation: use record syntax**

Instead of

```
data Car = Car String [String] Int [String]
```

Why not

```
data Film = Film { name :: String
                 , actors :: [String]
                 , released :: Int
                 , characters :: [String]
                 }
```

(I couldn't really tell what your last list of Strings was)

This way, you can construct a Film like this:

```
lotr :: Film
lotr = Film { name = "Lord of the Rings"
            , actors = ["Elijah Wood", "Ian McKellen", "Orlando Bloom"]
            , released = 2001
            , characters = ["Frodo", "Sam", "Pippin", "Merry"]
            }
```

And you automatically have accessor functions

- `released :: Film -> Int`
- `name :: Film -> String`
- and so forth

See also [LYAH # Record syntax](http://learnyouahaskell.com/making-our-own-types-and-typeclasses#record-syntax)

Comment: Haskell / Teaching Genius - you do not know how much help, how much sense and how much you just taught me. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 4):

The point is this:

```
[putStrLn(filter ((== chosenYear).y)) |  (w x y z) <- testDatabase]
```

You haven't understood list comprehension yet.
What you want is:

```
[ (Car w x y z) | (Car w x y z) <- testDatabase, y==choosenYear]
```

Probably.

With

```
 mapM (putStrLn . formatCarRow)
```

you have already ordered: *format and then print each element of the follwoing list*. Hence, the putStrLn in the list comprehension is utterly absurd.

Please note that putStrLn is in some way a misnomer: It won't print anything actually! It just constructs a thing that happens to cause printing when executed in the IO monad. It seems like this is hard to understand, but soon you will.

Comment: @Ingo: thanks for the reply (lol to the comment above, its for anothe piece of work so i had to chnge variable names :/ ) this is the error i got now:

 - Type error in generator
*** Term           : (w,x,y,z)
*** Type           : (a,b,c,d)
*** Does not match : Film

Comment: See my correction. DId miss that you have a data constructor. (Wasn't it a tuple yesterday?)

Comment: it was a tuple but i changed it to 'data' rather than 'type', it seems to be a lot less code with the other functions i had to do, i am struggling so much to understand this all i want to do is what you have done above but call the 'formatCarRow' to format the row in a specific way for printing - i have to do it in a way similar to this with no extra libraries to do it for me :/

Comment: What's the problem replacing formatFilmRow with formatCarRow? If I can give you an advice: don't do everything at once (formatting, handling lists of items, doing IO). Start writing formatCarRow or whatever you call it, that takes a Car and returns (not: prints!!!) a String. Test this function in ghci. If you're pleased with the result, come back and ask the question: I have a function Car -> String, how to I print a list of cars.

Comment: Okay i will try that, i am a beginner to this, how would i get it to return a string, i thought it was already?